# add href to string in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to get a `$string` to dynamically update an href link on my PHP page.

Code:

```
$_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Users have been successfully unarchived and moved to <a href="$string1">$string1</a>';
```

Comment: $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Users have been successfully unarchived and moved to <a href="$string1">$string1</a>'; here is full code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you might want to take a quick tour here: [tour] and also read [ask] when you ask a question.

Comment: when you use single quote the string is not parsed, you need to split string or use double quotes with escaping it. Also you can use sprintf() function